# Smarty check if id matches certain numbers

Tags: php, smarty, smarty3

**What i've got**: an if statement that checks if the page id is equal to the cms ID, i'm not that experienced with smarty code. So i didn't know exactly how to fix my problem.

```
{if $cms->id eq 10}
   {* Do Something *}
{/if}
```

**What i want**:
is that i have an array with multiple page id's and that it checks if one of these id's matches the `{$cms->id}`. I hope it is clear what i mean. Below i've added some php code that does the same, only i can get it to work in Smarty.

```
$numbers = array(10,20,30,40,50,60);
if(in_array($cms->id, $numbers, true)){
    /* do something */
}
```

Comment: have you tried -> `{if in_array( $cms->id, array(10,20,30,40,50,60))) } {* Do Something *} {/if}`

Comment: @Sean - Yes, i've tried that but that unfortunately isn't working either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `in_array`

Try

```
{if in_array($cms->id, $array)}
    {* some template *}
{/if}
```

$array must be assigned to template, creating array inside template is not possible with Smarty

Comment: I Used your code and it does exactly what i want. Thanks gave you a vote up

Answer (score 1):

You can use function substr_count()

```
{if substr_count($arrayString, $subString)}
    do Something
{/if}
```

Document at: [Php document](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php)